# was ue4 made in Qt?

Tags: qt, qtgui, win32gui, unreal-engine4

Unreal Engine 4 is a great piece of software. I wondered if anybody knew how the GUI editor was created. Did they use their own technology based on Windows (i doubt it though) or based on something else? Or did they build this with Qt or another library? This is a question that just keeps me wondering and i can't find a lot of info on the web.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be able to find out if you find any Qt libraries (`Qt*.dll` or `libQt*.dll`) somewhere in the UE4 program directory. Much more likely, though, the program sets up a window and does everything in OpenGL from then on. Why not ask Epic Games by email or on their forum? I'm sure a response isn't much effort so chances are high you'll get one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Unreal Engine Editor's UI is made using [Slate](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Slate/index.html) - an in-house UI system created by Epic explicitly for this. Slate is also used as the base for [UMG](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/UMG/index.html) (the UI tool inside the editor).

Answer (score 0):

They use their own tools to make the UE4 editor IDE. But this may change going forward.

Checking out the engine from source will require an ability to read code, but maybe someone knows where to look to begin modifying the interface. would be cool to modify editor interface using blueprints.